# Unexpected result when using toStringTag with Object.defineProperties

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Why does it not work and why does it behave so weird when I set [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) with [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) on a function/constructor? Why is it not the same as when I directly set the `toStringTag` symbol on the function/constructor?

```js
(() => {
  console.log('===== Expected Result =====')
  
  const Bob = function() {};
  Bob[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'George';
  
  console.log('Name: "%s"', new Bob().constructor.name);
})();

console.log('\n');

(() => {
  console.log('====== Actual Result ======')
  const Bob = Object.defineProperties(function() {}, {
    [Symbol.toStringTag]: { value: 'George' }
  });

  console.log('Name: "%s"', new Bob().constructor.name);
  
  // In Chrome DevTools console, the following will appear as
  // Object.defineProperties.value {}
  console.log('%o%c (See output in DevTools console)', new Bob(), 'color: transparent');
 })();
```

[image: Chrome DevTools output]

---

**Update:**

I created [an issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1111395) on the chromium bug tracker for the Chrome DevTools weird behaviour if anyone is interested.

Comment: Yeah, that’s pretty weird. Sure looks like a bug to me. (`{ configurable: true, value: 'George' }` gets you `Object.defineProperties.configurable`.) Maybe even a vulnerability if you’re lucky? :)

Comment: Although I don’t see you logging `new Bob()` with `%o`, and the second constructor’s name being an empty string isn’t weird.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn’t have anything to do with `toStringTag`. Try `new (Object.defineProperties(function () {}, { foo: { value: 'bar' } }))`

Comment: @Ry- You don't need to log `new Bob()` with `%o`, just type in `new Bob()` in the console and you'll get the same result.
Why the second constructor's name is an empty string?

Comment: Because you put it through a function instead of assigning it directly to a name. `const Bob = Object(function () {});` would also give `Bob.name === ""`.

Comment: Oh! So to set the toStringTag, the function or object needs to be assigned first?

Comment: Not to set the `toStringTag` specifically, but a function doesn’t automatically get a name without appearing in a specific place in relation to the name, right. So you could either call `Object.defineProperties(Bob, …)` separately, or also add a `name: 'Bob'` property.

Comment: Oh! Ok. I kind of understand but I don't see why the `toStringTag` symbol does not work even if the function has no name. In my mind, the function's name is supposed to be hidden or replaced by the `toStringTag` value no matter if the function has a name or not.

Comment: `toStringTag` is only for `Object.prototype.toString.call(Bob)`. That’s why I brought up the removed `console.log` with `%o` in the first snippet – it logs `Bob {}`, not `George {}`.

Comment: Aaah! That's why I was so confused! I don't know why I was thinking the function name was being replaced by the `toStringTag` value, it has never been the case. I guess the DevTools bug confused me and made me think that. Thanks a lot!